# Image with different sizes with `srcset` loads an image at seemingly random breakpoint

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, srcset

I have an image of a snoozing cat of which I have three different sizes; 320px, 700px and 1024px.

Here is what I am after: When the viewport is between 0 and 320px, load the 320px version; when it's 321px - 700px load the 700px version, and above that load the 1024px version.

Using the `srcset` attribute, I am able to get close to this behaviour; but the images that get loaded are not tied to the breakpoints I am providing in my `srcset`.

```html
  <img srcset="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/338546/cat-320w.jpg 320w,
      https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/338546/cat-700w.jpg 700w,
      https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/338546/cat-1024w.jpg 1024w"
    src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/338546/cat-1024w.jpg">
```

As you can see, the 700px version gets loaded in when viewport width is 237px, and the 1024 version gets loaded in when it's 424px.

To test this, I have use the Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab, and disabled the cache. The issue is replicable in my demo code.

Why does this happen, and how can I control the image size properly?